# How to use users custom name in Twilio Programmable video with node js

Tags: node.js, twilio

My script is working perfect, i am using this sample : https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node

i tried everything to connect users with custom name, but i cant do it. i am new in node js

you can see code at github

```
https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node/blob/master/public/video/quickstart.js
```

it is auto generating names. but i want to use my user's names. 
can you help me?